# C++ Inicializacion de un arreglo de estructuras

Tags: c++, estructuras

este es mi codigo:

```
struct objeto
{
    string etiqueta;
    string tipo;
    string descripcion;
    int codigo;
    int cantidad;
    bool existe;
}
articulo[21]= //Obviamente todos tendran datos diferentes
{
    articulo[0]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[1]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[2]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[3]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[4]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[5]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[6]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[7]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[8]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[10]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[11]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[12]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[13]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[14]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[15]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[16]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[17]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[18]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[19]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    articulo[20]={"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true}
};
```

En un programa que estoy haciendo previamente estoy definiendo todos los datos de cada objeto del arreglo articulo de la estructura

Pero el compilador me arroja una advertencia de compatibilidad, ¿Como lo arreglo?

Comment: sin modificar su codigo, primero que nada puede poner el mesaje de error completo podria ser algo como esto **warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11**, en el caso de ser como este trate de usar el flag `-std=c++11` para indicar al compilador que quiere trabajar con ese standard. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Angel, pero deseo que trabaje con el estandar normal

Comment: Cual es para usted (o en general) el standard normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin modificar su codigo, primero que nada puede poner el mesaje de error completo podria ser algo como esto:

> warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or
>   -std=gnu++11

En el caso de ser como este, trate de usar el flag **-std=c++11** o -**std=gnu++11**, o el que corresponda, para indicar al compilador que quiere trabajar con ese standard de C++.

---

Creo que `int *nombre = new int{1,2,3};` por ejemplo si necesita soporte para C++11 como minimo, pero `int nombre[] = int{1,2,3};` no hace falta<sup>1</sup>.

---

Quizas parte del error sea este ademas de lo anterior, pruebe asi:

```
articulo[21]= //Obviamente todos tendran datos diferentes
{
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true},
    {"Atlas Humano","Libro","Libro de anatomia humana",0,5,true}
};
```

Puedes mirar este ejemplo en ideone:

https://ideone.com/IqmDFE

*<sup>1</sup>Tengo mis dudas y no tengo acceso ahora mismo a C++, si no le funciona o no es correcto, y le es posible comunicarmelo por un comentario, para eliminar o ajustar la pregunta seria de agradecer.*

**Update:**

En este ide online tiene la opcion de c++ 98 y el codigo funciona bien, como le comente:

http://cpp.sh/6pefc

Comment: Muchas gracias Angel, has solucionado mi problema, aunque me despierta la curiosidad eso de "usar el flag -std=c++11 o -std=gnu++11" donde se integra eso?

Comment: @Malthael dependera de si esta usando un ide u otro, o si usa directamente g++ GCC, CLang u otro se activara de una manera u otra, puede averiguar si no lo sabe cual es el que usted esta usando, y despues ir a google y poner como "Como habilitar soporte para C++11 en ..." y el que usted este usando por ejemplo si usa CodeBlock pues eso. Saludos